# How to use Voronoi Tessellation on a 3D atoms block

Tags: python, voronoi

Currently I created a block made of some atoms using lammps, but they are just a bunch of points, which is not what I want. So I need to switch them to grains using Voronoi Tessellation. How can I make this happen for a 3D block with python? Thanks.